# How to use mercurial (Hg) within a Python application?

Tags: python, mercurial

Aloha!

Hg is a fine DVCS that is also a python module. This allows us to do ''import mercurial'' and load hg into our own application. My idea was to use mercurial within a Python application to create a revision controlled storage for my application.

However my google-fu semms to fail me. I can't find any documentation, tutorial or examples of how to use hg as a module in Python providing functionality. help(mercurial) lists the normal commands and dir() provides some hints of methods.

But do you for example create files for backing store, or do you get another type of data structure that works as a Hg repo?

There seems to be great potential for neatness having this functionality. But how?

Comment: It's not a great idea to do so, because the mercurial project makes no attempt whatsoever to keep backwards compatibility in the API between versions, and they're up front about this.

Comment: Do be aware that Mercurial is GPL (not LGPL), so if your application links to Mercurial in this fashion and is distributed you must place your application under the GPL too.  For that reason, and because it's the only API guaranteed to be stable, most integration is still done at the at the command line / process level, which is very stable and well documented.

Answer (score 6):

API is mostly undocumented, and using it might require you to release your code as GPL — see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi. The preferred (and more backwards compatible) way is to call hg CLI frontend.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. Basically this idea is bad due to Hg API instability and licensing. Hmmm, ok.

Running it through CLI calls is a way forward and as you state solves those issues neatly. Not as neatly as being able to revision control your data structures directly though - it would entail dumping (pickling) them into files for storage. Which you probably would have to do anyhow. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Thanks again!